# How to check the type of values in the Object

Tags: javascript

Suppose - I have a JS object

```
// Example
let obj = {
  name: "name",
  legs: [4.1, 5.3, 6.8],
  tails: 1,
  friends: ["everything!"],
  internalObj: {
    part_1: [22],
    part_2: ['str'],
    part_3: [],
    part_4: [[],[]]
  },
  ttt: ''
};
```

How can I check the type of key ...
How i can check that type is array or string or object or  array to arrays...

i made it

```
var keys = Object.keys(anyObj);
for (let key in keys ){
  console.log(typeof(key));
}
```

and i have next output

```
string
string
string
string
string
string
string
string
string
```

How to get the right type for key value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var keys = Object.keys(anyObj);
 for (let key in keys ){
      console.log(typeof(anyObj[key]));
 }
```

Comment: I don't know why, but only that variant of the condition works correctly   
`for (let key in anyObj)`

Answer (score 0):

Sure about array if you want to check in JS, Not sure about Array of an object, either way, you can check it with does it contains nested elements using for loop if it so then its there.

`Array.isArray(obj)`